# fetch from remote database and store into local django

Tags: python, mysql, json, django, python-3.x

There is a situation were I couldn't be able to see it done beforehand in python application and I'm wondering if this can be done at all.

The scenario is that there's a Django server(#1) acting as client here and another remote server which has a database(MySQL or SQL Server)(#2),

#1 should send a request with proper username and password and #2 should respond with json dump of its database to the #1, the server application structure of #2 is optional but Django is preferred, remember that we have several constraints here:

#### #2 does **not** have its own database username or password and should only use the username and password given by #1

#### #2 is **not** aware of the table structure of its own database but should be able to properly dump it as json

#### #1 should be able to send such HttpRequest and receive the json file as HttpResponse and save it as an object(or file)

BTW python version is 3.4 and Django version is 1.8, (both stable)

I think one way to do it is to execute a shell command after #2 receives the request but I'm pretty much mixed up in this(is it possible to run shell script in python?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could develop 2 sets of apis on both sides. Use [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) or [Tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), you can create api on server #2 to accept username and password from client #1, then process the dump. After your dump is properly created, server #2 will send the json by using the api on client #1.

Since you are sending json across the network I don't think you need shell script to get the dump. Python is also good at system operations.

Comment: I believe that the REST framework is very useful and the tutorials ive read represent how easily you can query via remote requests in less than 30 lines of code, however since the database server I'm talking about already exists with tables and data, the whole usage is spoiled. #2 server is not aware of the database table and columns before its ran, so unless there is a way to programmatically create models out of existing tables without hardcoding username and password either, the REST framework will not work. great solution otherwise, or am I missing something?

Comment: There is a way in django to create model based on existing database. Just one command `inspectdb` and you got all models magically. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/. But there might be manual verification do be done to make sure everything looks right.

Comment: the problem seems to be mostly fixed except the very first corner I was stuck with. in every Django doc it says that Django has to know the database parameters, but in this case Django should not know the database parameters before #1 gives it to #2, I mean, is there also a way to delay database connection until parameters are set, also is there a way to do the inspectdb and migrate command from python function inside program rather than Django-admin shell command?

Comment: I don't know enough about your purpose of creating this application, so I don't quite get what's the relationship between your "database parameter" and "server-client" architecture. People usually create apis on server so client could call to get information, server would have all the models, database connection settings etc. Client only fetch data but don't usually keep any info. Maybe it's not useful because you need something else.

Comment: I don't know, its just that in other frameworks you can connect to database server with a dynamic connection string inside your program and I was wondering if same could've been done in Django as well, well initially we thought to keep the database server acting like a database server(i.e passing username and password and connecting to it to query it and retrieve data) so it might be necessary to alternate the structure and let local server know db parameters(instead of original server(#1) which used to connect to this database server(#2)) and separately authenticate original server instead?